# Some controls of Google Map view are under status bar and toolbar

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps, android-fullscreen

I have an app with transparent toolbar and statusbar and there is map which takes all space of the display but I need to move native controls of Google's map view under toolbar somehow

[image]

How can it be solved? For example right now I can't reset rotation (click on circle button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `GoogleMap.setPadding()`

Implemented this solution (portrait mode only!):

```
val view = binding.root
val statusBarHeight = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    view.rootWindowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars()).top
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    view.rootWindowInsets.stableInsetTop
} else {
    // 24dp
    resources.getDimension(R.dimen.status_bar_height).toInt()
}
var topMargin = statusBarHeight
val tv = TypedValue()
if (requireActivity().theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
    val actionBarHeight =
        TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, resources.displayMetrics)
    topMargin += actionBarHeight
}

googleMap.setPadding(0, topMargin, 0, 0)
```